# Как переустановить nopcommerce приложение?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Друг скинул приложение nopcommerce, которое уже было установлено и работало у него на компе. При попытке запустить у меня пишет ошибку "Не найден экземпляр БД". Чтобы это решить есть два варианта:

1) Изменить строку подключения к базе

2) Переустановить nopcommerce, т.к. при начальной установке почти автоматически настраивается путь к базе

Вопрос. Как мне пойти по второму пути, т.к. по первому я не уверен что строка верная?

Comment: Если Вам не нужно сохранить старые настройки, которые были на сайте друга, тогда Вам лучше будет скачать с оф сайта новую версию и установить по новой.
Если нужно сохранить, тогда в папке App_Data найдите файл Settings.txt, и там пропишите путь к старой базе данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалил файлы Settings.txt и InstalledPlugins.txt и ConnectionString в web.config

Comment: nopcommerce не хранит строку подключения ConnectionString в web.config

Comment: при подключении к бд или изменении данных в файле setting.txt меняется строка полждключения

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обновить до самой свежей версии

Выполните следующие шаги: 
Откройте страницу с архивами последней версии.
Сделайте резервную копию всей информации на Вашем сайте, в том числе базы данных. Это чрезвычайно важно, чтобы вы всегда смогли вернуться к последней работающей версии сайта независимо от того, как пройдет миграция. 
Необходимо обновлять nopCommerce пошагово, от версии к версии. Если ваша текущая версия 2.00 а вы хотите обновиться до 2.30, сначала вам необходимо обновиться до 2.10, потом до 2.20 и т.д.
После того, как сценарий обновления загрузится, выполните его на вашей базе данных.
Удалите все файлы из предыдущих версий. При развертывании убедитесь, что файлы App_Data\Settings.txt и App_Data\InstalledPlugins.txt не перезаписаны.
Скопируйте обратно файлы Settings.txt и InstalledPlugins.txt из директории App_Data.
Проверьте, что все работает корректно.

**Важно:** если вы храните изображения в файловой системе, то сделайте их резервное копирование (\Content\Images) и скопируйте обратно обновленные. 
(warning) Важно (обновление версий с 1.00 по 2.00): если вы хотите обновиться с версии 1.90 до текущей версии, вам необходимо установить версию 2.00 сначала (поверх существующей базы данных), запустите SQL сценарий миграции, и потом обновляйтесь до 2.10, 2.20, 2.30 и т. д.